# ReactJs how to know when a component is removed from DOM

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently facing a problem with React. I need to know when a component is removed from DOM.

All I find in component lifecycle is componentWillUnmount which gets called before the component is removed from DOM.

Is there any way to achieve this with React ?
In plain javascript ?

Thanks.

[EDIT]

@jpdelatorre
"Plain javascript" === Not using a library ;-)

My use case is the use of jsPlumb within a react component.

Basically jsPlumb is a library that draws svg in the DOM with position calculation.

In my main component there is a list of items. 
Each item is a component.
On each rendered item I use JsPlumb to draw on it.

But... When I remove an item of the list the items are changing there positions in the DOM so I need to ask to jsPlumb to redraw things based on new positions. So that's why I need to know when component is fully removed from DOM.

Comment: Can you expand your question a little bit... maybe provide your use case why you want to do this. What do you mean with "plain javascript"? Not using a library? not using ES6 features?

Comment: @jpdelatorre see my [EDIT] for further informations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok thanks to all ! I found a solution that fits my needs and is (IMHO) clean...

In my parent component I handle componentDidUpdate lifecycle event and in there I can know (with prevProps and props) if the changes that are made need to fire my action...

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
    // this one is called each time any props is changed
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
       // if condition is matched then do something
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

`componentWillUnmount` is the correct lifecycle method. As you say, it is triggered prior to the component being removed. If you have something you need to wait to to until after it's been removed, you can use `setTimeout` with a short timeout value to schedule a callback once the current task completes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Setting a timeout is currently what I'm doing... I was looking for a "cleaner" solution but thanks !

Comment: @pitrackster: As far as I know, there isn't one. The only places in the React source I can find calls to `componentWillUnmount`, it's followed by actually unmounting it, with no intervening yield back to the browser and no further calls to the component.

Answer (score 1):

componentWillUnmount is the life cycle method which can be hooked.

But as mentioned if you want to know in component1 about unmounting of component2 then you need to trigger an action in component2 in its lifecycle method, which should be subscribed in component1 and do some action in component1 listener.

Comment: Yep that's how I handle it now, with a timeout ... I see from everyone answer that there is no other solution...

Comment: why timeout ?. You can acheive by subscribing to an event which gets triggered by another component.

Comment: componentWillUnmount don't tell me when the component is really removed from DOM but says "hey I'm gonna be removed...Soon or later" ... that's why I need to use a timeout... Because I need to do something after the component has desappeared !

Answer (score 1):

As other already mentioned you need `componentWillUnmount`.
Here is a simple example in React(I added there some comment to get what is going one):

```
var Button = React.createClass({
  componentWillUnmount: function(){
      // console will show this message when compoent is being Unmounted("removed")
        console.log('Button removed');
  },

  render() {
    return <h1 ref='button_node'>
    <ReactBootstrap.Button bsStyle="success">Red</ReactBootstrap.Button>
    </h1>;
  }
});  



var RemoveButton = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
     // this state keep tracks if Button removed or not
     //(you can use it for some redrawing or anything else in your code)
     return {buttonMounted: true}
  },

  mountRedButton: function(){
    ReactDOM.render(<Button/>, document.getElementById('button'));
    this.setState({buttonMounted: true});
  },

  unmountRedButton: function(){
    ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(document.getElementById('button'));
    this.setState({buttonMounted: false});
  },

  render() {
    return <h1>
      //based on condition if Button compoennt removed or not we show/hide different buttons
      { this.state.buttonMounted ? <ReactBootstrap.Button onClick={this.unmountRedButton } bsStyle="danger">Remove Red Button!</ReactBootstrap.Button> : null}
      { this.state.buttonMounted ? null :<ReactBootstrap.Button onClick={this.mountRedButton } bsStyle="success">Add Red Button!</ReactBootstrap.Button> }        
    </h1>;
  }
});


// mount components    
ReactDOM.render(<Button/>, document.getElementById('button'));
ReactDOM.render(<RemoveButton/>, document.getElementById('remove'));
```

Here is a full working example on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p6buojuf/)

As about "plain javascript" - you are already using React JS,my example is based on React and ReactDom, nothing more(actually there is also react-bootstrap, I added it only for pretty buttons, it is not required at all)

**Update:**
What about use of [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)? If you need a time when Node in DOM is removed but `componentWillUnmount` is fired before node removal(which seems unsutable for you) you can use it. Following my example with buttons:

```
var removalWatcher = new MutationObserver(function (e) {
    var removalTimeStamp = '[' + Date.now() + '] ';
  if (e[0].removedNodes.length) {
    console.log('Node was removed', e[0].removedNodes, 'timestamp:', removalTimeStamp)
  };
});
```

here is a [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p6buojuf/1/) with updated example. You can compare timestamps that are printed into console both for `MutationObserver` and React `ComponentWillUnmount`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Unfortunately it does not solve my problem.   If I want to wait for 'red button' to be removed from DOM I need to use a timeout with an arbitrary time... which is not reliable IMO... But it seems there is no other way...

Comment: @pitrackster can you explain more. When do you need an event? when button is removed , before, or after?

Comment: Sorry I did not see the unmountComponentAtNode part... But I can't use that because I'm looping through data to render my components... I need to know when the button is removed from DOM